# Installing SparkR doesn't work

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I want to install "SparkR" and get the following error message:

> install.packages("SparkR") Warning in install.packages :   cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found' Installing package into ‘C:/Users/A0D3D55/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) Warning in install.packages :   package ‘SparkR’ is not available (for R version 3.4.0) Warning in install.packages :   cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'

I have installed the new R version 3.4.0, but with the verion 3.3.3 the Installation doesn't work either. Someone know why this doesn't works?

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't works because of a timeout. I find this page from Apache (https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/R) and will try it out. But how can I execute .sh? How can I install SparkR? Sorry I'm not a programmer. :)

Comment: @zero323, whoops sorry. Still, `SparkR` is not on CRAN. @user43348044 You might want to have a look at `sparklyr` though.

Comment: @Axeman Indeed, though it is work in progress :)

Comment: @user43348044 Since you need a full Spark installation, which comes with SparkR out-of-the box, I would just download Spark binaries and add R package to path. You'll find all the details in the linked question.

Comment: Please read the answers carefully. At least doesn't depend on sparklyr or RStudio at all.

Comment: @zero323 Yes, I want SparkR and not sparklyr. And a full Spark Installation would be nice with a IDE. But the linked question is about installing on a RStudio Server and thats not what I want, because I use RStudio local. And where I get the Installation with the lib? Sorry for my questions. I have install Spark and Export the files "C:\Spark\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\R\lib\SparkR"

Comment: When I try this command I get an timeout: devtools::install_github('apache/spark@v2.1.1', subdir='R/pkg') and with the other command which is postet there (jsonlite::fromJSON("https://api.github.com/repos/apache/spark/tags")$name) I get an error, too: Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : Couldn't connect to server